# Using the fingerprint scanner as middleclick mouse button

Tags: mouse, fingerprint-reader

On Android, it is possible to reconfigure the fingerprint sensor to some more useful functions, for example with [Fingerprint Gestures](https://lifehacker.com/fingerprint-gestures-turns-your-fingerprint-sensor-into-1788928125)

Is this possible on Ubuntu too?

(At the moment, I use Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo yoga 720-15IKB, but I would be happy to find a solution for a future Ubuntu version also)

The Fingerprint module doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04 right now. I find no device using `fprint_demo`.

The Fingerprint sensor is called "Synaptics WBDI". The only device using `lsusb` is:

```
$ lsusb |grep Synap
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:0081 Synaptics, Inc.
```

But that might also be the Touchpad.

There are some hits for Synaptic checking `hwinfo`

```
$ hwinfo
  ...
  P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6
  N: bus/usb/001/004
  E: BUSNUM=001
  E: DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/004
  E: DEVNUM=004
  E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6
  E: DEVTYPE=usb_device
  E: DRIVER=usb
  E: ID_BUS=usb
  E: ID_MODEL=0081
  E: ID_MODEL_ENC=0081
  E: ID_MODEL_ID=0081
  E: ID_REVISION=0164
  E: ID_SERIAL=06cb_0081_9413a800b66b
  E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=9413a800b66b
  E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ff0000:
  E: ID_VENDOR=06cb
  E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=06cb
  E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Synaptics, Inc.
  E: ID_VENDOR_ID=06cb
  E: MAJOR=189
  E: MINOR=3
  E: PRODUCT=6cb/81/164
  E: SUBSYSTEM=usb
  E: TYPE=255/16/255
  E: USEC_INITIALIZED=2015135

  P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0
  E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0
  E: DEVTYPE=usb_interface
  E: ID_USB_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Vendor Specific Class
  E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Synaptics, Inc.
  E: INTERFACE=255/0/0
  E: MODALIAS=usb:v06CBp0081d0164dcFFdsc10dpFFicFFisc00ip00in00
  E: PRODUCT=6cb/81/164
  E: SUBSYSTEM=usb
  E: TYPE=255/16/255
  E: USEC_INITIALIZED=4293294

...

50: USB 00.0: 0000 Unclassified device
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: MtLc.g9F1G8rI369
  Parent ID: k4bc.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 1-6:1.0
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "Synaptics Unclassified device"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x06cb "Synaptics, Inc."
  Device: usb 0x0081 
  Revision: "1.64"
  Serial ID: "9413a800b66b"
  Speed: 12 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v06CBp0081d0164dcFFdsc10dpFFicFFisc00ip00in00"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #52 (Hub)
```

In Windows, it shows up as:

```
Synaptics WBDI
USB\VID_06CB&PID_0081\9413A800B66B
USB\VID_06CB&PID_0081&REV_0164
Bios name: \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06
\Device\USBPDO-4
PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1400)#USBROOT(0)#USB(6)
ACPI(_SB_)#ACPI(PCI0)#ACPI(XHC_)#ACPI(RHUB)#ACPI(HS06)
oem3.inf:542d598d9aceb7d5:Biometric_Install.NT:5.5.2603.1050:USB\VID_06CB&PID_0081
Driverkey: {53d29ef7-377c-4d14-864b-eb3a85769359}\0000
```

Maybe [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503565/cant-figure-out-how-to-check-if-biometric-is-present) will give a hint, how to address the Biometric Device.

Comment: how does it show up as a device? if it's an evdev device we should be able to configure it to do what you want with xinput... check this out: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_buttons .... if you can post some more info on your device maybe we can figure out how to remap the buttons.... if it's not so simple we might need to create a translator app like I did for the contour shuttleXpress https://github.com/Shamanon/shuttled

Comment: look in the output of lspci and lsusb

Comment: I cannot find the fingerprint sensor there. what do i have to look for?

Comment: @rubo77 it's the first hit: `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:0081` as confirmed by Windows registry key: `USB\VID_06CB&PID_0081`

Comment: You pointed out quite well, that there is no solution right now, so this will stay open, until hopefully one day, there will be one ;)

Comment: **:D :D :D**  Like I said: it'll take someone wanting to become a kernel developer or an existing kernel developer wanting this feature...

Answer (score 5):

What Google did is [a hack](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/search?q=fingerprint+gesture&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&project=art&project=bionic&project=bootable&project=build&project=cts&project=dalvik&project=developers&project=development&project=device&project=docs&project=external&project=frameworks&project=hardware&project=kernel&project=libcore&project=libnativehelper&project=packages&project=pdk&project=platform_testing&project=prebuilts&project=sdk&project=system&project=test&project=toolchain&project=tools): a fingerprint reader can be considered a tiny touchpad and fingerprint gestures can be generated by the Android Kernel to then let applications act upon it.

However in the Linux Kernel, [no one is working on that](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/?h=v4.17-rc5&qt=grep&q=fingerprint+gesture) so if you'd want something like this it would mean:

- Becoming a kernel developer
- Developing this yourself so it works for you
- Getting blasted by Linus Torvalds for breaking something else  **;-)**
- Re-doing it properly
- Nirvana!

### Sorry! :-(